# I don't have the Ubuntu software center on 20.4

Tags: software-installation, software-center, software-uninstall

I'm trying to follow this instruction to install zoom: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZYuKEQZr4k

but he shows ubuntu software center and I don't see it. Is it because I'm running it on macbookair m1 ARM in parallels?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 2):

It really should not matter if you are running Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine. Although I have no knowledge of Ṕarallels', I think the software center should be there. 
Seeing this video https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=install+ubuntu+in+parallels#kpvalbx=_fPJnYtHQLNSDur4PzqKAoAc13 (it is on youtube), I see that it is more limited though. Might be that is due to being the ARM version.
Look what software is installed. And then use the command-line (terminal).
***Install***

You can install Ubuntu Software like so:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-software
```

or install Gnome Software in newer releases of Ubuntu like so:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

***Reinstall***

You can reinstall Ubuntu Software like so:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-software
```

or reinstall Gnome Software in newer releases of Ubuntu like so:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software
```

***Reset***

You can reset Ubuntu Software to its vanilla settings.

First, purge it like so:

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-software
```

Then, install it like so:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-software
```

or reset Gnome Software in newer releases of Ubuntu.

First, purge it like so:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-software
```

Then, install it like so:
`sudo apt install gnome-software`  
It works the same for Zoom.
`Sudo apt install zoom`